# C# google oauth2 check authentication state

Tags: c#, authentication, google-oauth

Is there any way to check if the user is already logged in or not?

```cs
this.userCredential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
  clientSecrets.Secrets,
  new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, emailScope, profileScope },
  Globals.GetGDUserName(),
  CancellationToken.None
);
```

I am using the above code to authorize the user, but it automatically prompts the user to select account if no one is already logged in.

So, is there any way to check if the user is already logged in.

If I put this code in initialization function, it might prompt the user even if he doesn't want to, that's why I am looking for the way to check if the user is already logged in.

I did find something like `prompt = none`, but how can I use that in the code above or in any other way?

Answer (score 1):

In the `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer` object, you can set the prompt parameter to `"none"` and customize the process to indicate that you do not want to prompt the user for authorization if they are not yet logged in. In addition; You can use the token value to check that the user has been before. If there is a token or not, you can perform the relevant transactions.

```
var initializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    ClientSecrets = clientSecrets.Secrets,
    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, emailScope, profileScope },
    DataStore = // Specify data store,
    Prompt = "none"
};

var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer);

var token = await flow.LoadTokenAsync(userId);

if (token == null)
{
    // User is not logged in - your code
    this.userCredential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        clientSecrets.Secrets,
        new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, emailScope, profileScope },
        Globals.GetGDUserName(),
        CancellationToken.None
    );
}
else
{
    // User is already logged in
    this.userCredential = new UserCredential(flow, userId, token);
}
```

[Data Store](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Auth/latest/api/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer.html#Google_Apis_Auth_OAuth2_Flows_AuthorizationCodeFlow_Initializer_DataStore)
[User credentials](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#user-credentials)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I too found a way very similar to this.